# OUTPUT OF array.shape in NUMPY

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape, shapes

I have a NUMPY ARRAY and I reshaped it using ARRAY.reshape(1,50), which means it has only 1 row and 50 columns. But when I type  ARRAY.shape, the output is (50, ). Why is that so? Isn't the output misleading? Because you get the same output for an array with 50 rows and 1 column. So why is the output same for arrays with clearly different shapes?

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Comment: could you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the value, but you don't catch it. You have to assign the value to a variable.
Try this: x = x.reshape(1, 50)

Comment: Okay got it. But if you type
'''x = np.linspace(0,5,50)
x.shape'''

The output is (50, ) even though the shape is clearly 1x50. Isn't it confusing?
The output is expected to be (1,50).

Comment: I think it is something you get used of if you use it long enough.